# Cast a function as variable

Tags: c#, .net

Let be the following function `Measure` for measurement of execution time for some functnion `method`

```
public static TimeSpan Measure(Action method)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    method.Invoke();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

This method is launched by the following line of code

```
var ExecTime = ComplexityCounters.Measure(() => method(int a, int b));
```

As we can see it's a very huge recall of `Measure`, so, let's try to short it by the following function

```
public static TimeSpan ExecTime (Action method)
{
   var ExecutionTime = Measure(() => method.Invoke());
   return ExecutionTime;
}
```

But

```
var ExecTime = ExecTime(method(int a, int b));
```

gives the error c# cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'. How to fix it ? Or may  be is there a way to compose those two function in one ?

Comment: Notice that the parameter type of `ExecTime` and the parameter type of `Measure` are exactly the same, so they need to be called the same way, e.g .`ExecTime(() => method(a, b))`.  And that your "working" line of code doesn't

Comment: What do you mean by "very huge recall"? `() => method.Invoke()` is just `() => method()`, which is unnecessary wrapping that has to close on the `method` parameter. I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist and creating unnecessary levels of indirection in the process.

Comment: did it this way `public static TimeSpan ExecTime (Action method)
        {
            Action a = () => method();
            var ExecutionTime = Measure(a);
            return ExecutionTime;
        }` so now it works as `var ExecutionTime = ExecTime(() => method);`

Comment: Over-engineered. Creates two delegate instances each time instead of one and accomplishes the same thing. They way you started your question was just fine.

Comment: @madreflection you are right, it is unnecessary level

Comment: Just I have a long function names + varaibles, so i thought about to make them more short, now I see that it can be recalled in two lines more good way for me `Action a = () => method(); var ExecutionTime = Measure(a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here full example

```
public static TimeSpan Measure(Action method)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        method.Invoke();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }

    public static TimeSpan ExecTime(Action method)
    {
        var ExecutionTime = Measure(() => method.Invoke());
        return ExecutionTime;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var spentTime = ExecTime(() => Sum(1,2));
    }

    public static int Sum(int t1, int t2)
    {
        return t1 + t2;
    }
```

actually you are declaring your variable `ExecTime` same as your method name `ExecTime`

Comment: also you are not passing action to `ExecTime` as per your example.